# Android setImageBitmap on onActivityResult don't work sometimes

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, onactivityresult

I have an ImageView and want to set imagebitmap for it when receive data on onActivityResult().
But sometimes setImageBitmap() don't work. I don't know why? Can anyone help me to fix this issue? I tested on Galaxy S2 NTT Docomo.
This is my code :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 0) { 
           bitmap = .... //I got bitmap by some function here, data get from Intent data below
           imgUpload.setImageBitmap(bitmap); //imgUpload is an ImageView I init it onCreacte function
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this on Your `onResume()` also

```
imgUpload.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: I tried solutions but sometimes ImageView still not working with setImageBitmap.

Comment: I had the same problem but when i added this on onResume it was solved..just try to reclean your project and restart eclipse. This wil l help you

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. sometimes, when you get to this line, the image is not saved yet. ( saving a pic can take some time).

Put your function that create and save your bitmap in an AsyncTask, and display the thumb in postExecute